# Code to do geometric transformation equivalent to dragging by mouse in circle

Tags: graphics3d, rotation, geometric-transform

We can click and drag `Graphics3D` objects. Suppose you click and drag on such an object in the center of it and move your pointer of mouse in a circle of radius `r`.

If I wanted to do the same by code instead of mouse what would be the equivalent geometric transformation?

I tried using code with parameter `fi`, but it is behaving strangely, not as expected.

```
GeometricTransformation[graphics,RotationTransform[{{1, 0, 0}, 
   RotationMatrix[fi, {1, 1, 1}] . {1, 0, 0}}, (0,0,0}]]
```

Comment: "Strangely" - what is happening exactly? If you describe the problem, it's easier to propose a solution. Also please include complete executable code, for instance including a sample graphics object to work on, values of fi, and how you used your code for visualization.

Comment: I mean I can not figure out the required transformation.  Just evaluate `Graphics3D[Cuboid[], SphericalRegion -> True]` then click somewhere in the middle of the object and drag by mouse in a circle. Then do the same with code using `Manipulate` or `Animate`.

Comment: It is clearly some rotation. But you should define more clearly what rotation you want. About a fixed axes or about a moving axis.

Comment: The default option for ``"RotationControl"`` in [`Graphics3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics3D.html) is ``"ArcBall"``. Therefore, you should look online for the equations of the _arcball camera_ ([example](http://courses.cms.caltech.edu/cs171/assignments/hw3/hw3-notes/notes-hw3.html)).

Comment: @Daniel Huber: What is not clear? Exact same transformation that dragging by mouse is doing on 3D objects + mouse is doing circle on the screen. It is perfectly stated. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/273253/find-minimal-covering-sets-for-n-times-n-times-n-grid-covering-means-each-gri/273282#273282

Comment: This is not easy to translate in code. But if you can specify what rotation (s?) about which axes  you want it seem doable.

Answer (score 2):

Likely not the simpler approach or the smoother movement. I want the ViewPoint to move in a circle around the current ViewPoint. This is a circle on a sphere. I get a bunch of points on this circle, order them and use them to adjust the ViewPoint in animate.

```
g = Graphics3D[Cuboid[]]
vp = Options[g, ViewPoint][[1]][[2]];
d = EuclideanDistance[{0, 0, 0}, vp];
fi = Values[
   FindInstance[
    EuclideanDistance[{0, 0, 0}, {x, y, z}] == d && 
     EuclideanDistance[vp, {x, y, z}] == 0.4, {x, y, z}, Reals, 300]];
nr = NestList[Flatten[Nearest[fi = DeleteCases[fi, #], #], 1] &, 
   fi[[1]], 299];
Animate[
Show[g, ViewPoint -> n],
 {n, nr}]
```

[image]

The following shows the initial camera position (ViewPoint) in red and the circular ViewPoints generated by 300 points for the animation.

```
Show[g, Graphics3D[{Point[nr], Red, Point[vp]}]]
```

[image]